How to deal with multiple types on var_arg in c++?
How to do that?
The code is causing: null pointer dereference.
10-08 17:26:00.835  5249  5617 D DigestGenerator:  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (strstr+) ()

10-08 17:26:00.835  5249  5617 D DigestGenerator:  XXbase.apk!libtest.so (test_bool(char const*)+) ()

bool test_bool(const char *filename) {
    if (strstr(filename, "yes")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

long *test_long(long number, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, number);
    for(int i=0; i<number; ++i) {
        if (test_bool(va_arg(args, const char *))) {
            //do something
            return 0;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
    //do something
    return 0;
}

test_long(0, 1, "yes", 3);


Show how you're calling test_long().

My guess is the first argument is more than the number of remaining arguments.

There's no built-in way to know the type of a varargs argument, you need to encode it somehow yourself. For instance, printf() determines the types from the format string.

There is no way to "deal". You have to know the types, there is no dealing with it. The code is causing: null pointer dereference. is filename null?

No, filename is not null. I'm trying: test_long(0, 1, "yes", 3);

If that is the case then your loop never runs

test_long(0, 1, "yes", 3) - but 1 and 3 are not a const char *. You can't call va_arg(.., const char*) when the argument is not a const char*.

How can I perform a checking if argument is const char*?

You can't perform a checking. You have to know the types beforehand. Once you pass them via va_args, the types are lost. You can represent the types, like test_long(0, "int", 1, "const char*", "yes", "int", 3) and then you have to cerefully handle every single type separately and be very very vigilant to handle every single case in order. For example printf encodes the types in the format string "%d %s %d", parses the format strng in a big switch and handles every single type separately, in pseudocode like if(%d) { va_arg(va, int); } if (%s) { va_arg(va, const char *); }

Use a variadic template instead, and then your type information won't be lost.  i.e. template <typename... Args> long test_long(Args... args) { ... }

C-style variadic arguments don't carry any type information with them.  Your function has to know what args are there before trying to read them.  For instance, printf uses the format string to determine what types of arguments are present.  You could do something similar, i.e.
long test_long(std::string_view types, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, types);
    for (char c : types) {
        if (c == 'l') {
            long l = va_arg(args, long);
            // do something with l
        } else if (c == 's') {
            const char* s = va_arg(args, const char*);
            // do something with s
        } else {
            // unknown type
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    test_long("llsl", 0, 1, "yes", 3);
}

Demo
This is fairly brittle though, and you have to explicitly handle every possible type.

A more C++-style approach would be to use a variadic template instead of C-style va_args.  For instance:
template <typename... Args>
long test_long(Args... args)
{
    bool results[] = { test_bool(args)... };
    // do something with the results
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    test_long(0, 1, "yes", 3);
}

Demo
This may be a bit more complex simply due to C++ templates being complex, but its far more type safe than the C-style approach since the type of arguments isn't lost.
In embedded context this may have the downside of increasing code size though, since each different set of parameter types results in a separate function being instantiated from the template.

Your template example does not compile, as you still can't pass 1 and 3 to test_bool() (your demo is not actually demonstrating what this code is showing). You can simply overload test_bool() for non-string inputs (demo). Or you can use if constexpr to test if a given argument is (compatible with) a char* before treating it as such (demo).

@RemyLebeau Yes, I was assuming the "real" test_bool was a family of functions that's overloaded for different types.

To be accurate, templates do not increase code size, they may increase the executable size depending on how many templates are instantiated, but the code itself won't change by itself :)

@Fareanor Machine code is still code.  Most MCUs refer to "code ROM" or similar, which is what's getting eaten by increased (executable) code size.

Your template can type-erase the data and forward them to a single implementation. The house keeping chore of type-erasure needs to be handled, either manually or automatically; the cost of code size inevitable in either case. If type-erasure is not possible, again the cost of code-size is inevitable; somebody must produce the code for each special case; either a clean template, or a mess of multiple functions/overloads.
